# How to compare dates in decision action in oozie job workflow

Tags: datetime, workflow, action, oozie

I have 3 scripts to process in one Oozie job. Say job a, b and c.
b and c are already running for several days say from 11-1. I want to include a as well so three of them will run parallelly in the future. 
For job a, I want it to catch up with the old days when b and c already did. I give start time as 11-1 as well, so a will start running from 11-1. 
Here I give decision action:

```
<switch>
    <case to="eadp-hive-bf4-old">
        ${TIMESTAMPnow} gt ${TIMESTAMP}
    </case>
    <default to="eadp-hive-bf4-events"/>
</switch>
```

What i want it to do is, when the current time is larger than nominal time, run only a;
when the current time is current with nominal time which is by default, run all 3 jobs.

The gt comparison (greater than) is not working properly, and neither is `&gt;` working.

There's a isDir EL I could use to check the exact directory for my old jobs for b and c, but since I use datetime as partition, the datetime part of the path is not in a good pattern, besides there's no proper string functions to substring.

Is there a way to compare the current datetime and nominal datetime in workflow actions so it could make the right decision?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your expression inside ${ ... } and your timestamps should be comparable (longs or ISO strings). Example:

```
${TIMESTAMPnow gt TIMESTAMP}
```